# jQuery CSS Style a parent div when child is focused

Tags: jquery, parent-child, parent, css

I have a script like this: (but it's not working)

```
$('div#selectbox select:focus').parent().css('box-shadow','0 0 4px 1px #5099E2');
```

When the user focuses on a `select` that's parent is `div#selectbox` I want to change the `box-shadow` of the `div` any suggestions?

Here is a jsFiddle of what I'm doing... http://jsfiddle.net/2BydK/

Comment: Please add some of the HTML markup and css for context.

Comment: I might be wrong, but box-shadow is not widely supported, some browsers require prefix for certain properties like `-o-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow` etc.

Comment: Mention the exact reason why it isn't working. What problems you're facing with it.

Comment: @Nazariy I add those in later... while it's under construction, I just want to make sure it works in my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the code will do a good job of finding a focussed select element, but there is nothing to trigger it. Perhaps try this:

```
$('div#selectbox select').focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('box-shadow','0 0 4px 1px #5099E2');
});

$('div#selectbox select').blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('box-shadow','none');
});
```

If you wanted to add an check in there, you could always put in a `if($(this).is(":focus")){}` just to be sure. Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you very much, here the fiddle with your script and the original: http://jsfiddle.net/2BydK/1/

Comment: you should chain those events, to prevent repeated selection of the same elements

Answer (score 3):

try the jQuery `focus()` instead

```js
$('div#selectbox select').focus(function() {
  $(this).parent().css('box-shadow','0 0 4px 1px #5099E2');
});
```

```css
div { margin: 10px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectbox">
  <select>
    <option>option one</option>
    <option>option two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('div#selectbox select').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().css('box-shadow','0 0 4px 1px #5099E2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

since you want to style to be applied to during the focus you want to grab the `focus` [event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) of the select box, then apply the style to it's parent.

```js
$('div#selectbox select').focus( function() {
  $(this).parent().css('box-shadow','0 0 4px 1px #5099E2')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectbox" style="margin: 20px; padding:10px;">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in pure CSS so no JavaScript is needed.

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would help for cases like this and will help with accessibility when people use tabbing for navigating, common when using screen readers.

```
div#selectbox:focus-within {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #5099E2;
}
```

---

> The :focus-within pseudo-class matches elements that either themselves
>   match :focus or that have descendants which match :focus.

You can check which browsers support this http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within